# docker run mongo image on a different port

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

The short question is can I run mongo from mongo:latest image on a different port than 27017 (for example on 27018?)

If yes, how can I do this inside a docker-compose.yml file in order ro be able to type the following command:

```
docker-compose run
```

The longer story:

I have an app running in AWS EC2 instance. The app consists of a mongodb and a web application. Now I decided to separate part of this app into its own microservice running in the same AWS inside docker container (two containers one for another mongo and one for a web app). I think the problem is I can not have mongodb running on port 27017 and at the same time another mongodb running inside a docker container on port 27017. Right? I have this assumption because when I stop the first mongo (my app mongo), my docker mongo works.

So I am trying to make the second mongo (the one that is inside the docker container), to run in a different port and my second web app (the one inside another docker conianter), to listen to mongo on a different port. Here is my attempt to change the docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
    webapp:
        image: myimage
        ports:
            - 3000:3000

    mongo:
        image: mongo:latest
        ports:
            - 27018:27018
```

And inside my new app, I changed the mongo url to:

```
monog_url = 'mongodb://mongo:27018'
client = MongoClient(monog_url, 27018)
```

Well, the same if I say:

```
monog_url = 'mongodb://mongo:27018'
client = MongoClient(monog_url)
```

But when I run docker-compose run, it still does not work, and I get the following errors:

```
ERROR: for mongo  driver failed programming external
connectivity on endpoint: Error starting userland proxy:
listen tcp 0.0.0.0:27017: bind: address already in use
```

Or

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError:
mongo:27018: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Default communication between different containers running on the same host

I solved the problem, not by running the container in a different port though, but by learning one new feature in docker-compose version 2 and that is we do not need to specify links or networks. The newly created containers by default will be part of docker0 network and hence they can communicate with each other.

As [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1318694/matt) mentioned, we can run processes inside containers on the same port. They should be isolated. So the problem can not be that the docker container and the host are using the same port. The problem is perhaps there is an attempt to forward a used port in host to another port in container.

Below is a working docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
    webapp:
        image: myimage
        ports:
            - 3000:3000

    mongo:
        image: mongo:latest
```

I looked at the mongo:latest docker file in github, and realized they exposed 27017. So we do not need to change the port or forward host ports to the running mongo container. And the mongo url can stay on the same port:

```
monog_url = 'mongodb://mongo:27017'
client = MongoClient(monog_url, 27017)
```

## Docker run an image on a different port

So the above solution solved the problem, but as for the question title 'docker run mongo image on a different port', the simplest way is just to change the docker-compose to:

```
version: '2'
services:
web:
    image: myimage

mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    command: mongod --port 27018
```

Mongo is now running on 27018 and the following url is still accessible inside the web:

```
monog_url = 'mongodb://mongo:27018'
client = MongoClient(monog_url, 27018)
```

Comment: Adding the command line worked for me when none of the other solutions did. Thanks very much for that!

Comment: You saved my day.

Answer (score 69):

You can tell MongoDB to [listen on a different port](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.port) in the configuration file, or by using a command-line parameter:

```
services:
  mongo:
    image: 'mongo:latest'
    command: mongod --port 27018
    ports:
        - '27018:27018'
```

Comment: This has not solved the problem yet. I looked at the github code for mongo:latest and they expose port 27017 and they run command mongod. I guess that their mongod command with 27017 runs before my command mongod --port 27018. What do you think?

Comment: Actually it is the answer to my question of how to run mongo in a different port (although it was not necessary to do so to solve my problem) It runs mongo on port 2718. Just no need to do port forwarding 27018:27018. Port 27018 is already accessible in the private network by using: mongo:27018

Answer (score 15):

You can run processes inside a container and outside on the same port. You can even run multiple containers using the same port internally. What you can't do is map the one port from the host to a container. Or in your case, map a port that is already in use to a container.

For example, this would work on your host:

```
services:
    webapp:
        image: myimage
        ports:
            - '3000:3000'

    mongo:
        image: 'mongo:latest'
        ports:
            - '27018:27017'

    mongo2:
        image: mongo:latest
        ports:
            - '27019:27017'
```

The host mongo listens on 27017. The host also maps ports 27018 and 27019 to the container mongo instances, both listening on 27017 inside the container.

Each containers has its own network namespace and has no concept of what is running in another container or on the host.

#### Networks

The webapp needs to be able to connect to the mongo containers internal port. You can do this over a [container network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/) which allows connections between the container and also name resolution for each service

```
services:
    webapp:
        image: myimage
        ports:
          - '3000:3000'
        networks:
          - myapp
        depends_on:
          - mongo

    mongo:
        image: 'mongo:latest'
        ports:
          - '27018:27017'
        networks:
          - myapp

networks:
    myapp:
        driver: bridge
```

From your app the url `mongo://mongo:27017` will then work.

From your host need to use the mapped port and an address on the host, which is normally `localhost`: `mongo://localhost:27018`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not still working for me. I assumed that putting 'links' for one container, automatically makes a private network between the two? Maybe I am wrong. Any suggestions of how to start mongo on a different port inside the container?

Comment: By default containers are attached to the `docker0` bridge which doesn't allow inter container communication unless you setup `links`.  You'd have to modify the mongo config. Maybe create your own [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) `FROM mongo` and `COPY` the config into your new image to [build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/)

Comment: The first part of your answer is correct: "By default containers are attached to the docker0 bridge" I do not think the second part is: "which doesn't allow inter-container communication unless you setup links". Actually by default they can because they are in the same network. Unless I understand your meaning differently.

Comment: Matt, you were really close to solve my problem, I found most part of your answers accurate so I gave you +1. However, keeping mind of your guide, I made changes to my docker-compose file and ran it differently to solve my problem. So I will not accept yours as the final answer.

Comment: @MahshidZeinaly The docker0 bridge is firewalled by iptables rules, so although "connected" containers can't communicate by default. What I didn't realise was v2 docker-compose files now create a custom network by default, so you don't need to specifically define one.

Comment: docker-compse v2 is exactly what I came up with just minutes ago. So posted an answer to my own question. My question title is different though and I did not even need to change the ports, so I tried to explain everything in a separate answer. Thanks again for letting me know that containers can run on the same ports...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem
I changed ports in my docker-compose.yml file and this work for me
In doing so, i don't change port in my connection string

```
mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27018:27018"
```