# Cannot Connect to MongoDB in Docker MAC

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have a docker-compose.yml like this:

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment: 
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD= 
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postresql/data
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME = root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD = mongopw
    ports:
      - 64000:64000
    volumes:
      - mongodata:/var/lib/mongodb/data
volumes:
  pgdata: 
  mongodata:
```

For the information, i also have mongodb installed on my Mac with default for 27017, so in docker-compose i have change the port to 64000.

After run:
`docker compose up -d`

then the mongodb container is runing successfully. But when i try to connect mongodb://localhost:64000/ and fill the username/password, its not successfully connected, its say time out and `connection <monitor> to 127.0.0.1:64000 closed`

this is the latest logs in docker mongodb:

```
2023-11-13 08:43:38 {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-13T01:43:38.544+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20625,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture","attr":{"dataDirectory":"/data/db/diagnostic.data"}}
2023-11-13 08:43:38 {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-13T01:43:38.547+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":6015317, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Setting new configuration state","attr":{"newState":"ConfigReplicationDisabled","oldState":"ConfigPreStart"}}
2023-11-13 08:43:38 {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-13T01:43:38.547+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22262,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor starting"}
2023-11-13 08:43:38 {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-13T01:43:38.549+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock"}}
2023-11-13 08:43:38 {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-13T01:43:38.549+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"0.0.0.0"}}
2023-11-13 08:43:38 {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-13T01:43:38.549+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
```

and this is the inspect data:

```
{
    "Id": "927f21a1be452c4d02583178f4287ccc1942526d9c4c12211f3145b007355dca",
    "Created": "2023-11-12T02:45:43.333860629Z",
    "Path": "docker-entrypoint.sh",
    "Args": [
        "mongod"
    ],
    "State": {
        "Status": "running",
        "Running": true,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 33642,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2023-11-13T01:43:37.811177127Z",
        "FinishedAt": "2023-11-13T01:43:36.145856655Z"
    },
    "Image": "sha256:8b33e239cde686e9378f9d8941eafa167fdf73527e9e006ab1fe9174c9622797",
    "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/927f21a1be452c4d02583178f4287ccc1942526d9c4c12211f3145b007355dca/resolv.conf",
    "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/927f21a1be452c4d02583178f4287ccc1942526d9c4c12211f3145b007355dca/hostname",
    "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/927f21a1be452c4d02583178f4287ccc1942526d9c4c12211f3145b007355dca/hosts",
    "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/927f21a1be452c4d02583178f4287ccc1942526d9c4c12211f3145b007355dca/927f21a1be452c4d02583178f4287ccc1942526d9c4c12211f3145b007355dca-json.log",
    "Name": "/carsties-mongodb-1",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "Driver": "overlay2",
    "Platform": "linux",
    "MountLabel": "",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "AppArmorProfile": "",
    "ExecIDs": null,
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": null,
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "NetworkMode": "carsties_default",
        "PortBindings": {
            "64000/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "64000"
                }
            ]
        },
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "Name": "",
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
        },
        "AutoRemove": false,
        "VolumeDriver": "",
        "VolumesFrom": null,
        "ConsoleSize": [
            0,
            0
        ],
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "CgroupnsMode": "private",
        "Dns": null,
        "DnsOptions": null,
        "DnsSearch": null,
        "ExtraHosts": [],
        "GroupAdd": null,
        "IpcMode": "private",
        "Cgroup": "",
        "Links": null,
        "OomScoreAdj": 0,
        "PidMode": "",
        "Privileged": false,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "UTSMode": "",
        "UsernsMode": "",
        "ShmSize": 67108864,
        "Runtime": "runc",
        "Isolation": "",
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "Memory": 0,
        "NanoCpus": 0,
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
        "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "Devices": null,
        "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
        "DeviceRequests": null,
        "MemoryReservation": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "MemorySwappiness": null,
        "OomKillDisable": null,
        "PidsLimit": null,
        "Ulimits": null,
        "CpuCount": 0,
        "CpuPercent": 0,
        "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
        "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Source": "carsties_mongodata",
                "Target": "/var/lib/mongodb/data",
                "VolumeOptions": {}
            }
        ],
        "MaskedPaths": [
            "/proc/asound",
            "/proc/acpi",
            "/proc/kcore",
            "/proc/keys",
            "/proc/latency_stats",
            "/proc/timer_list",
            "/proc/timer_stats",
            "/proc/sched_debug",
            "/proc/scsi",
            "/sys/firmware"
        ],
        "ReadonlyPaths": [
            "/proc/bus",
            "/proc/fs",
            "/proc/irq",
            "/proc/sys",
            "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
        ]
    },
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Data": {
            "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/67cd3f0bfd2e23b6a4fa92fd3d4bf550394d5ef27d7195ee58deb9dc56a2c760-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/443a254ee0c0a06b34b8b70599da0760bcee4907fe1aa6314e6148300da739c3/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e00db7eb68eda6585b116e2ca87308b6b254111e8f6add739484fc55203aabae/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/96db55ee1ec6845e498e9c3d493c0c333471e6582ec5f97b449bb5c5363a37ca/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ed2a8aaf03d745ae10ed88e152ff8370f6db50f9c46e90227077114dab96e366/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/83f6f3a9c0ef02a16dccc92ce15b4de563cc6a88d515509eab0473c5fe51fb0f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6d26ba2e90ba6a464642f7856d54238eb740d0829d09ba1230405a48ec5a23ea/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b93b7d15cb9dd53a31c734a76309dd91d7997219a89d77c26cba1d27540a8e0c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4ba2f453781215e435fbd9157954fea8b67393245eb76ea93c112ded23b7a6db/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4167a9211d2cad305d015c36d65c4df822fc6006cb440e65cc53699925e6a820/diff",
            "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/67cd3f0bfd2e23b6a4fa92fd3d4bf550394d5ef27d7195ee58deb9dc56a2c760/merged",
            "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/67cd3f0bfd2e23b6a4fa92fd3d4bf550394d5ef27d7195ee58deb9dc56a2c760/diff",
            "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/67cd3f0bfd2e23b6a4fa92fd3d4bf550394d5ef27d7195ee58deb9dc56a2c760/work"
        },
        "Name": "overlay2"
    },
    "Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "volume",
            "Name": "bee5271abaaa2568a1c745835e639d9f9ed90354c0f152060ca6d98388d88fa3",
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/bee5271abaaa2568a1c745835e639d9f9ed90354c0f152060ca6d98388d88fa3/_data",
            "Destination": "/data/db",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        },
        {
            "Type": "volume",
            "Name": "carsties_mongodata",
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/carsties_mongodata/_data",
            "Destination": "/var/lib/mongodb/data",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "z",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        },
        {
            "Type": "volume",
            "Name": "98c5d21b2acce69b0bfecd3b77fcd0fb11ee3e5cbe2262bfe5680a11ea86b1a7",
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/98c5d21b2acce69b0bfecd3b77fcd0fb11ee3e5cbe2262bfe5680a11ea86b1a7/_data",
            "Destination": "/data/configdb",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        }
    ],
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "927f21a1be45",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": true,
        "AttachStderr": true,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "27017/tcp": {},
            "64000/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": false,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME = root",
            "MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD = mongopw",
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "GOSU_VERSION=1.16",
            "JSYAML_VERSION=3.13.1",
            "MONGO_PACKAGE=mongodb-org",
            "MONGO_REPO=repo.mongodb.org",
            "MONGO_MAJOR=6.0",
            "MONGO_VERSION=6.0.5",
            "HOME=/data/db"
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "mongod"
        ],
        "Image": "mongo",
        "Volumes": {
            "/data/configdb": {},
            "/data/db": {}
        },
        "WorkingDir": "",
        "Entrypoint": [
            "docker-entrypoint.sh"
        ],
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "bb22342274669aba1d8cf88e61e869f5fc8d14d078e6e6f142bcc847f8fb1b15",
            "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
            "com.docker.compose.depends_on": "",
            "com.docker.compose.image": "sha256:8b33e239cde686e9378f9d8941eafa167fdf73527e9e006ab1fe9174c9622797",
            "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "carsties",
            "com.docker.compose.project.config_files": "/Volumes/ASHafizullah/My Project/Udemy/Demo/Carsties/docker-compose.yml",
            "com.docker.compose.project.working_dir": "/Volumes/ASHafizullah/My Project/Udemy/Demo/Carsties",
            "com.docker.compose.service": "mongodb",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.22.0",
            "org.opencontainers.image.ref.name": "ubuntu",
            "org.opencontainers.image.version": "22.04"
        }
    },
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "fb773b8b8cbf094061cf0cc468152916c22f0332f2227d8b492c5419b2105562",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {
            "27017/tcp": null,
            "64000/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "64000"
                }
            ]
        },
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/fb773b8b8cbf",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "",
        "Gateway": "",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "",
        "IPPrefixLen": 0,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "",
        "Networks": {
            "carsties_default": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": [
                    "carsties-mongodb-1",
                    "mongodb",
                    "927f21a1be45"
                ],
                "NetworkID": "9e676644805e156450490f03fc9e6a3653b606cb41e98cc5370cc36b09a95e3f",
                "EndpointID": "e1b9f5a58cf471abe17e3ff31ae925cbe04d9c740496cf7658969ed197704a92",
                "Gateway": "172.21.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.21.0.2",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:15:00:02",
                "DriverOpts": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mapping the container port 64000 to host port 64000 is all well and good but you also need to have `mongod`/`mongos` _listening on that port_. [As per this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76002890/1431750), add a `command: --port 64000` to your compose file for the `mongodb` section. Or with `command: mongod --port 64000` [as per this other answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42716066/1431750)

Comment: I'd suggest changing the second `ports:` number to the default MongoDB port 27017, but this is also covered in the linked question.